# class NP, polynomial-time verification CLIQUE

Tags: theory, np, clique-problem

The CLIQUE problem-- problem of finding the 
maximum clique in a graph is NP-complete. 
That is, CLIQUE is

a.) in NP and 
b.) there is an NP complete problem, 3-SAT for one, 
that reduces to CLIQUE in polynomial time.

Part (b) above is fine-- all over in every resource and very well explained. 
For Part (a), from what i know, we need to have the following:
Given a specific solution instance, we need to show that 
it can be verified, in polynomial time, that that solution is an answer to this problem. 
So for instance, given a specific graph and a subgraph of it, we should be 
able to check whether that subgraph is a clique of maximum size in that graph.

The resources I've read so far are phrasing this 
Part (a) here as "easy, straightforward, etc" or 
"it can be shown in O(n^2) time that the given subgraph is a clique/not". 
However, the verification here is not just whether it's a clique, but also is whether it is a maximum clique in the graph. 
How can this be decided in polynomial time?

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the *optimization version* of the problem with the *decision version* of the problem.

The decision version of clique asks if the graph has a clique of size k.  Given a candidate solution, you can test its feasibility in polynomial time. Focus on the decision versions for NP-completeness proofs.

Certificates of optimality for the optimization problems are indeed harder to come by.

Comment: clique enumeration is NP-hard-- no polynomial time decision on that one. the Q here is-- WHAT IS THE CERTIFICATE OF THE PROBLEM< HOW DOES ONE DETERMINE THAT. whats the difference between the certificates, if any, of CLIQUE, HALF-CLIQUE, MAXIMUM-CLIQUE-CONTAINING-A-SPECIFIC MEMBER. these are stuff you see errors on in literature. i dont need the distinction between decision & optimization.